# JavaScript: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var elem = $('#'+ id)[0];
var children = elem.children[0].children;
var duration = children[1].innerText;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

(на 2-й строке). Но если я попытаюсь вывести в консоль переменную `children`, мне возвращется не `undefined`, а то, что мне и нужно - потомки элемента `elem`. Если же я пытаюсь вывести в консоль `children[1].innerText`, я получаю то, что мне и нужно. Почему тогда я получаю ошибку?
Если вывести в консоль `console.log(children.toString());`, то выводится [object HTMLCollection]. Вот html код (который подгружается динамически):

```
<div class="song local" id="pc-9" url="some path">
    <ul>
        <li class="name">Bob Dylan - Blowin' in the wind</li>
        <li class="duration">2:49</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "на 2-й строке" и "вывести ... переменную `children`" - противоречат друг другу. В случае ошибке во 2-й строке, переменная `children` назначена не будет. Постарайтесь переформулировать вопрос. Разметка html тоже будет полезна.

Comment: Если вы работаете с динамически создаваевыми элементами то такое возможно, просто непроинициализированный елемент на странице появляеться и js его не видит.

Comment: но на следующей же строке console.log(children); выдает не undefined

Comment: вот html разметка:
<div class="song" id="pc-9" url="Bob Dylan - Blowin' in the wind.mp3"><ul>
  <li class="name">Bob Dylan - Blowin' in the wind</li>
  <li class="duration">2:49</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: @JohnBlumen пожалуйста помните, что комментарии не предназначены для показа Вашего кода. Перенесли Ваш код в текст вопроса.

Comment: @JohnBlumen уточните пожалуйста у Вас код `HTML`  для которого не работает `jquery` подгружается динамически или нет?

Comment: @JohnBlumen - Поставьте себя на место людей, которые (по доброте душевной) попытаются Вам помочь. Добавили Вы кусочек html, и что? Три строчки кода, которые непонятно где находятся, с неизвестным значением переменной `id`, с переменной `children` возможно (скорее всего) объявлкенной где-то еще. Как эти добряки должны объяснить Вам проблему с Вашим кодом?

Comment: @Борис, скорей набирайте 50 репутации, вы сможете оставлять комментарии. )

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ваш код отрабатывает до того, как прогрузился весь **DOM** страницы. Когда вы вписываете что то в консоль - все отрабатывает, поскольку страница загружена. Чтобы быть уверенным, что этого не происходит оберните ваш код в `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var elem = $('#'+ id)[0];
   var children = elem.children[0].children;
   var duration = children[1].innerText;
});
```

Тогда можно быть уверенным, что код выполняется после подкрузки всего **DOM** страницы.

Comment: нет, код обернут в $(document).ready(), более того, он происходит куда позже загрузки страницы

Comment: @JohnBlumen А переменная еще нигде не присваивается?

Comment: Нет, нигде. Но если вывести в консоль children.toString() - выдает [object HTMLCollection], может, в этом проблема

Comment: @JohnBlumen А у тебя всегда такая структура? Мож проще селектор переписать, чем вот так маяться?